# How to find click event in a page using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am using this confirm plugin https://github.com/invetek/jquery-confirmon

If i click on home icon it shows confirmation message. However, I want to show this message only when any keyup and click event occurs on my page.

Here is my code:

```
$( "body" ).click(function(event) { 
    $('#home').confirmOn('click', function(e, confirmed){
    if(confirmed) { window.location='index.html'}
    else {
        //If we need to, we can do some actions here if the user cancelled the confirmation
    }
})
});
```

My above code works when I directly click on home without clicking on my page. And, also when I click on any field in the page it shows message but if i click on yes or no button in confirmation box its not navigating/working.

Comment: for click on page try `$(document).confirmOn('click', function(e, confirmed){`
instead of `$('#home').confirmOn('click', function(e, confirmed){`

Comment: I used your code. However, when i open the page itself it shows confirmation box..

Comment: there is no mistake in this code post your html code so that we can guess..1

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
$(document).confirmOn('click', function(event) { 
$('#home').confirmOn('click', function(e, confirmed){
    if(confirmed) { window.location='index.html'}
    else {
        //If we need to, we can do some actions here if the user cancelled the confirmation
    }
});
});
```